# Less Framework - Responsive Site

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm going to start my first responsive site and I've chosen Less for my framework - http://lessframework.com/

It's easily setup to add CSS for each device but it says its a grid framework too yet I don't see any grid css. Could this easily be added in to allow myself to easily setup the layout? I'm not really that good with setting these kind of things up.

Comment: good question I took a look and I don't see any css presets for grids....

Answer (score 2):

Less Framework doesn't include pre-defined grid css. The idea is that it provides you with the widths of various columns in a grid at each breakpoint, which you can then use to create your layout.

For what you're looking for, I would suggest using something like the [1140 Grid](http://cssgrid.net/) or the [Golden Grid System](http://goldengridsystem.com/). Personally, I think the Golden Grid is pretty cool, but it has its issues (it doesn't support IE6-8, for example, which can be a pretty big problem depending on your project).

If you're dead set on using the Less Framework, you could definitely roll your own grid CSS using the values in it. If you're not comfortable with that, you would probably benefit from a different system.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what Alex said.

You may want to try something like the Grid pack tool which is a GUI that will let you define your target screen sizes and then export the corresponding Less file.

http://gridpak.com/about/

The Twitter bootstrap also uses less

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html

Hope this helps.

L

Comment: Added + due to introducing gridpak.